# UIButton with a gradient layer not highlighting

Tags: objective-c, ios

created a button with a gradient layer:

```
//MyGradient creates and returns gradient layers
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [MyGradient blueGradient];

//MyButton is a subclassed UIButton which adds some attributes
MyButton *testButton = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
testButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 10, 150, 50);
[testButton addTarget:self action:@selector(testButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[gradient setFrame:testButton.bounds];

testButton.clipsToBounds = YES;
[testButton.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];    

[self.view addSubview:testButton];
```

how can i get the image to highlight when pressed? I've found a couple of example code that subclass a UIButton and overrides drawRect: method. is there a simpler way to get the button to highlight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button does not have an image - so there's nothing to highlight.

Set an image (a gradient image, if you want) as the button's background ... and even if you DON'T set an image for UIControlStateHighlighted, the button will "highlight" - basically, iOS will invert colors.

Also, if you need only horizontal / only vertical gradients, you might want to chech this function out : [resizableImageWithCapInsets](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/resizableImageWithCapInsets%3a)

Have fun !

Comment: Add that's it's pretty straightforward to generate the image using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` and friends.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in way to do that. Either overload UIButton and draw the gradient yourself in `drawRect` based on the state of the button, or create 2 gradient images for the two states and use `setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal` / `UIControlStateHighlighted`.

Comment: I caution against overriding `drawRect:` unless you really need to, and know what you are doing. By the time you handle all the button state changes and sizing issues, you're better off just generating an image and letting the existing UIButton code do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to put your gradient in an image file (preferably resizable) and using code such as:

```
[testButton setImage:normalStateImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[testButton setImage:highlightStateImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```